SwiftUI+MapKit cannot display the globe view on iPhone
I hope to use SwiftUI and MapKit to achieve the effect of a globe view when zooming out on the map. The code works in Xcode’s simulator and Simulator, but when running on my iPhone, it only zooms out to a flat world map. I haven’t found anyone else encountering the same issue, so I’d like to ask where the problem might be.
Below is the simple code:
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct GlobalTest: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(position: .constant(.automatic), interactionModes: [.all, .pan, .pitch, .rotate, .zoom]) {
        }
        .mapStyle(.hybrid(elevation: .realistic,
                              pointsOfInterest: .including([.park]),
                             showsTraffic: false))
    }
}

#Preview {
    GlobalTest()
}

I have also tried setting the camera properties, or using "struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable" "view.mapType = .satelliteFlyover", but it still doesn’t work. My phone is an iPhone 15 Pro Max, running iOS 17.5.1, and I am in mainland China. The Xcode version is the latest. If anyone understands the reason, please let me know. This is very important to me, and I would be very grateful!

For info, could not replicate your issue, all works well for me in my tests. The Map is shown as the globe when zooming out on the map.
Maybe there are some settings for Map or your App on the iPhone that can be changed.
On MacOS 14.5, using Xcode 15.4 and 16.0-beta, tested on real iOS 17 devices and macCatalyst.

Thank you so much! May I ask if you have set any permissions or additional features? For example, location access permissions. I currently suspect that some other unnoticed settings might be causing this issue on my phone.

No, I did not set any special permissions or additional features. It seems to just work. But you could be correct, that some settings/permissions may be responsible for your issue.

OK, it's so weird, thanks again!
